# Create a list with length 10: for the first component list[[1]]

Tags: r

Create a list with length 10: for the first component list[[1]], the dimension is 1, the second is 1*2, the third is 3*3, the fourth is 4*4, and so on. The values should be selected randomly from 1:100.

For each component in the list, select the values > 50 and write a function to calculate a value = sd (values)/mean(values) when length(values)>1, otherwise return 0.

Loop for each component, you will get 10 values, and then calculate the sum of the 10 values

here is what i have done,and i don't know how to do next.

```
x1=runif(1,min = 1,max = 100)
x2=matrix(runif(2,min = 1,max = 100),1,2)
x3=matrix(runif(9,min = 1,max = 100),3,3)
x4=matrix(runif(16,min = 1,max = 100),4,4)
x5=matrix(runif(25,min = 1,max = 100),5,5)
x6=matrix(runif(36,min = 1,max = 100),6,6)
x7=matrix(runif(49,min = 1,max = 100),7,7)
x8=matrix(runif(64,min = 1,max = 100),8,8)
x9=matrix(runif(81,min = 1,max = 100),9,9)
x10=matrix(runif(100,min = 1,max = 100),10,10)
list=list(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10)e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
# filter values above 50
foo <- function(x) {
  v <- x[x>50]
  # if more than one, return sd/mean
  if (length(v)>1)
    sd(v)/mean(v)
  # return 0 otherwise
  else
    0
}

# calculate the sum of foo applied to the 10 components of the list
sum(sapply(1:10, function(i) foo(matrix(runif(i^2, min=1, max=100), i))))
```

But if `foo` is applied on the entire matrices (is it the case?), then you do not need the matrix step?

```
sum(sapply(1:10, function(i) foo(runif(i^2, min=1, max=100))))
```

Comment: Thank you verymuch!Can you explain every single step?

Comment: Sure. `foo` function is already quite commented, let me know if you have troubles. `sapply` will apply `foo` on the numbers sampled from `runif` and arranged (or not) as a matrix. eg at the 4th step, `i=4`, we sample 16 numbers and we arrange them in a 4 x 4 matrix  on which `foo` is applied.